# SSRS IF Number of selected parameters Expression

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to display the parameters within the footer for a reference to the reader of the printed report.

```
=IIF(Count(Parameters!P_Faculty) >3, "%", "Faculty"&join(Parameters!P_Faculty.Label, ", "))
```

I wanted to do a count on the number of options of a parameter which are selected so I can limit the display to "%" if there are more than 3 Faculty Parameters selected.

I receive no run-time error instead the text box displays "#ERROR". I'm guessing my error is with the `Count(Parameters!P_Faculty)>3`

How could I simulate this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it turns out I was going about this the wrong way.

I did not know that Parameters have their own Count value:

```
Parameters!P_UIO_ID.Count
```

Full solution:

```
=IIF(Parameters!P_UIO_ID.Count > 3, "%", join(Parameters!P_UIO_ID.Label, ", "))
```